# getInitialProps не работает асинхронно

Tags: reactjs, rest, nextjs, ssr

При заходе на страницу отрабатывает функция **getInitialProps** и только после обработки запроса обрабатывается запрос и на фронтенде (см. **useEffect**)

Получается, при нажатии на ссылку сайт словно подвисает,
только потом на некоторое время виден
текст `Loading page, please wait...`,
и затем уже контент страницы, на которую перешли.

Почему **getInitialProps** не работает асинхронно?

Код:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Header from '../components/header'
import Footer from '../components/footer'

export default function Work({ page: serverPage }) {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(serverPage)

  useEffect(() => {
    async function load() {
      const response = await fetch('http://uer/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/25')
      const result = await response.json()

      setPage(result)
    }

    if (!serverPage) load()
  }, [])

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Header pageName='Work' />
      {page === undefined ? <h2>Loading page, please wait...</h2> : <main dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: page.content.rendered }} />}
      <Footer />
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
Work.getInitialProps = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('http://uer/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/25')
  const page = await response.json()
  
  return page
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, рекомендуется не использовать `getInitialProps`  вместо него используйте `getStaticProps` или `getServerSideProps`. Это написано [**тут**](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps).

Во вторых желательно при возвращении результата через `getInitialProps` возвращать все внутри объекта `props` чтобы не было путаницы.

```
Work.getInitialProps = () => {
 
  return {
     props: {
        page,
     }
  }
}
```

В третьих зачем еще раз тот же запрос отправлять внутри `useEffect`?
Все уже один раз отправляется внутри `getInitialProps`. Зачем лишний запрос делать на клиенте?

И наконец `getInitialProps` работает полностью асинхронно. Все из-за этого метода `useEffect` который во второй раз отправляет запрос на клиенте. У вас есть два решения.

Либо удалите `getInitialProps` и вызывайте все внутри `useEffect` что по моему будет абсурдом так как зачем тогда вообще `next`.

Второй вариант который очевидно правильный все запросы отправляйте внутри `getInitialProps`. Ну кроме тех которые нужны после загрузки страницы когда пользователь взаимодействует с ним. `onClick`, `onChange` и т.д.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ, приму к сведению.  
От useEffect пока откажусь.